# In Microsoft Word 2011, how would I make a macro to select multiple numbers and copy them all to clip board

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, copy-paste

My situation: I have ~600 separate word documents with random 7-digit numbers interspersed throughout the text. I need to move each of these numbers over into an Excel spreadsheet. However, manually sifting through each document and picking out each number, copying it, and pasting it into Excel would take hundreds of hours.

Ideally, I need a macro that will automatically highlight all 7-digit numbers. That way, once all numbers in the document are highlighted, I can copy/paste them into Excel with the click of a button. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help! I was able to accomplish my goal using the following method. This method (which did not involve a macro) highlighted ALL numbers within my document (including my 7-digit numbers of interest in addition to other random, unwanted numbers such as dates, etc.)

1. Open the Find and Replace tool in Word.
2. Change the settings to this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/253vb.png)

This highlighted ALL numbers in my Word document.

3. I copied all of these numbers to my clipboard with Ctrl + C.
4. I pasted all of these numbers into Excel.
5. Using tools built into MS Excel, I was able to sort out and delete numbers that I was not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

For a single document, you could do the same thing without a macro, by using find and replace (3 separate ones).

IN A COPY OF YOUR DOCUMENT (ie don't do this in your original - or you will lose all the text other than 7 digit numbers).

1. Do a wildcard find to highlight all 7 digit numbers (make sure you have selected a colour for your highlighter pen before you do the replace).

[image]

2. Then run a find and replace to delete all text that is NOT highlighted and replace with a blank paragraph mark (so your 7 digit number don't all end up together on same line).

[find and replace all to delete text that is NOT highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rYbd.png)

3. Now you just need to do a final find and replace all, to replace 2 paragraphs with just one (you may need to repeat this a few times to close up all the gaps).

[delete duplicate blank paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c6IF.png)

All your 7 digit numbers should end up on separate paragraphs.  Just copy all your text and paste it into Excel, and each number should be in separate cell in that column.

For your macro, you just need to add a loop for all documents in a particular directory/folder to repeat the same steps.